# Get Injected services from ViewResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am in the OnResultExecuting of an ActionFilterAttribute

```
public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
{
    //here
    base.OnResultExecuting(context);
}
```

At this point the context.Result contains a ViewResult. The view will have (or has already) a service injected.

```
@model IMyModel
@inject IMyService MyService
```

I want to call a method on MyService.

```
public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
{
    var myService = //...
    myService.DoStuff();
    base.OnResultExecuting(context);
}
```

How do I get the object that will be injected? Or, can I provided the object that will be injected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do it through the `HttpContext`:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
...

var myService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IMyService>();
```

Comment: It does something. It does create a service, but It will create a new one for the view. However, that is probably Autofac doing that... I'll try to figure it out and come back if this indeed solved my problem.

Comment: Maybe you need to set it up as [SingleInstance](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#single-instance)

Comment: I need to set it per request, but that is fine, I had it default so per dependency,.. But then I got: 'Unable to resolve the type 'MyService' because the lifetime scope it belongs in can't be located. Which is probably caused the fact that the ActionFilter itself is not created by Autofac. Need to figer out how to do that. Currently: .AddMvc(options => options.Filters.Add<MyService>())